# Thread safety of primitive value type properties - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, crash, primitive

**Question**

I am working on a project where I am concerned about the thread safety of an object's properties. I know that when a property is an object such as an `NSString`, I can run into situations where multiple threads are reading and writing simultaneously. In this case you can get a corrupt read and the app will either crash or result in corrupted data.

My question is for primitive value type properties such as `BOOL`s or `NSInteger`s. I am wondering if I can get into a similar situation where I read a corrupt value when reading and writing from multiple threads (and the app will crash)? In either case, I am interested in why.

**Clarification - 1/13/17**

I am mostly interested in if a primitive value type property is differently susceptible to crashing due to multiple threads accessing it at the same time than an object such as NSMutableString, custom created object, etc. In addition, if there is a difference when accessing memory on the stack vs heap relative to multithreading.

**Clarification  - 12/1/17**

Thank you to @Rob for pointing me to the answer here: [stackoverflow.com/a/34386935/1271826](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34386935/1271826)! This answer has a great example that shows that depending on the type of architecture you are on (32-bit vs 64-bit), you can get an undefined result when using a primitive property.

Although this is a great step towards answering my question, I still wonder two things:

- If there is a multithreading difference when accessing a primitive value property on the stack vs heap (as noted in my previous clarification)?
- If you restrict a program to running on one architecture, can you still find yourself in an undefended state when access a primitive value property and why?

I should note that here has been a lot of conversation around atomic vs nonatomic in response to this question. Although this is generally an important concept, this question has little to do with preventing undefined multithreading behavior by using the atomic property modifier or any other thread safety approach such as using GCD.

Comment: Using atomic properties avoids any chance of reading "corrupt" values. But it doesn't necessarily avoid reading "incorrect" values.

Comment: Right, I am familiar with using atomic vs nonatomic, but is reading a "corrupt" value for a primitive value type property possible? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you run the code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386935/1271826 on a 32-bit target, you'll see corrupted values.

Answer (score 2):

If your primitive value type property is `atomic`, then you're assured it cannot be corrupted because your reading it from one thread while setting it from another (as long as you only use the accessor methods, and not interact with the backing ivar directly). That's the entire purpose of `atomic`. And, as you suggest, this only applicable to fundamental data types (or objects that are both immutable and stateless). But in these narrow cases, `atomic` can be useful.

Having said that, this is a far cry from concluding that the app is thread-safe. It only assures you that the access to that one property is thread-safe. But often thread-safety must be considered within a broader context. (I know you assure us that this is not the case here, but I qualify this for future readers who too quickly jump to the conclusion that `atomic` is sufficient to achieve thread-safety. It often is not.)

For example, if your `NSInteger` property is "how many items are in this cache object", then not only must that `NSInteger` have its access [synchronized](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1), but it must be also be synchronized in conjunction with all interactions with the cache object (e.g. the "add item to cache" and "remove item from cache" tasks, too). And, in these cases, since you'll synchronize all interaction with this broader object somehow (e.g. with GCD queue, locks, `@synchronized` directive, whatever), making the `NSInteger` property `atomic` then  becomes redundant and therefore modestly less efficient.

Bottom line, in limited situations, `atomic` can provide thread-safety for fundamental data types, but frequently it is insufficient when viewed in a broader context.

---

You later say that you don't care about race conditions. For what it's worth, Apple argues that there is no such thing as a benign race. See WWDC 2016 video [Thread Sanitizer and Static Analysis](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/412/?time=753) (about 14:40 into it).

Anyway, you suggest you are merely concerned whether the value can be corrupted or whether the app will crash:

> I am wondering if I can get into a similar situation where I read a corrupt value when reading and writing from multiple threads (and the app will crash)?

The bottom line is that if you're reading from one thread while mutating on another, the behavior is simply undefined. It could vary. You are simply well advised to avoid this scenario.

In practice, it's a function of the target architecture. For example on 64-bit type (e.g. `long long`) on 32-bit x86 target, you can easily retrieve a corrupt value, where one half of the 64-bit value is set and the other is not. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386935/1271826 for example.) This results in merely non-sensical, invalid numeric values when dealing with primitive types. For pointers to objects, this obviously would have catestrophic implications.

But even if you're in an environment where no problems are manifested, it's an incredibly fragile approach to eschew synchronization to achieve thread-safety. It could easily break when run on new, unanticipated hardware architectures or compiled under different configuration. I'd encourage you to watch that [Thread Sanitizer and Static Analysis](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/412/?time=753) video for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In your first paragraph, are you saying that mutable objects such as NSMutableStrings cannot be corrupt by multithreading? If so, they definitely can. The question that I asked is centered around primitive value types being corrupted by multithreading. Also, can you explain why primitives can or cannot be corrupted by multithreading. I realize that the purpose of `atomic` is to prevent  corruption, but are primitives susceptible to multithreading the same as objects?

Comment: First, my qualification re objects said "immutable and stateless", not "mutable" (and technically even that is not entirely correct, but you get the idea). Second, `atomic` primitive properties can not be corrupted because the synthesized accessor methods will synchronize all access (e.g. if you're currently reading on one thread, the write on another will wait until the read is done, and vice versa).

Comment: Finally, I can't reconcile your final question, "are primitives susceptible to multithreading the same as objects?" with your assurance that you understand what `atomic` does. The `atomic` synchronizes all accessors methods to the property, so by definition, that means that as long as you only use the property's accessor methods, that you cannot corrupt the primitive property through multiple threads. With objects, `atomic` merely ensures the integrity of the pointer to the object, but obviously not the object itself, which is why mutable objects are generally a problem in multi-threaded code.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I think the disconnect is that I am not concerned how the `atomic` property attribute works. I am interested in if a primitive value type property is differently susceptible to crashing due to multiple threads accessing it at the same time than an object such as NSMutableString, custom created object, etc. In addition, if there is a difference when accessing memory on the stack vs heap relative to multithreading. I will add this clarification to my original question. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You are wondering if primitive type properties are "susceptible to crashing due to multiple threads accessing it at the same time". No, when you have `atomic`, that memory is synchronized so it can _not_ be accessed at the same time. And so if you have, for example, `NSInteger localVar = self.intProperty`, the `localVar` is fundamentally (no pun intended) a local copy at different memory address. So no simultaneous access to the memory for the ivar backing that  original property is possible (as long as you don't dereference it, access the ivar directly, etc.).

Comment: Again, I am not concerned with the `atomic` property attribute. Nor am I concerned about local variables.

Comment: "I am not concerned with `atomic` property attribute" ... OK, if you're not worrying about `atomic` properties, then what precisely _are_ you concerned about? Are you wondering what happens if the property is `nonatomic`? I'm not trying to fight you here, but I'm just trying to understand what the real question is...

Comment: Bottom line, if we're talking about properties that have the `atomic` attribute (whether explicitly supplied or simply those that don't bear the `nonatomic` qualifier; properties are `atomic` by default), then the above discussion applies. And if you're talking about anything other than `atomic` properties, then you enjoy no synchronization at all, and you have to synchronize it yourself for thread-safety.